# usability of current compilers with c++ concepts

Tags: c++, language-lawyer, c++-concepts, c++20

A long time ago I started to read about c++ concepts. After a while a lot of things were dropped and concepts lite was born. But also concepts lite did not make its way to the C++11/14/17 standard.

As I read, the c++ standard committee decided to add again concepts to the c++17 draft. https://www.reddit.com/r/cpp/comments/6ngkgc/2017_toronto_iso_c_committee_discussion_thread/

There is also a new proposal for concepts, which can be found here:
http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2017/p0734r0.pdf

and it differs from the older one:
http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2015/n4377.pdf

I am now a bit confused about all the docs are around.

But what did that mean for currently available implementations? Can the current gcc 7.2 compiler already be used to try first steps with concepts? Has anyone checked out how different the available implementation is away from the new working drafts? Because I have some difficulties to read the sepcs and drafts ( i am not a language lawyer ) it would be nice if someone can explain the main deltas between the current implementations of e.g. gcc to the last working draft.

Hint:
For others which want also test it, simply enable concepts in gcc 7.2 with: `--std=c++17 -fconcepts`